# WordPress site redirecting to http://womanatwork.inhttp/womanatwork.in/

Tags: wordpress

My website domain name is womanatwork.in and I have just migrated my site from old server (Shared hosting) to new server(VPS Hosting) and this is multi site.
I have done all the setting like database,files and wp-config.php settings and all.
but I when I am opening my website by entering my domain name womanatwork.in  then it automatically redirected to http://womanatwork.inhttp/womanatwork.in/.

However wo-admin is working fine.
**Content of .htaccess file is**

[HTACCESS File si]https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeUKQ.png

Comment: have you checked the urls in the db? also, is it possible to share your vps setup? like the virtual hosts, `.htaccess`, and such..? the clues are too few to narrow down the possibilities.

Comment: Okay sharing the content of .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

Did you change already the siteurl and home url in the database? Check the screenshot below. It can be changed in `wp-options` table. You should change all occurrences of `http://womanatwork.inhttp/womanatwork.in/` to `http://womanatwork.in` in your database.

[image]

Comment: Done but http://womanatwork.inhttp/womanatwork.in/ is not in whole database

Comment: @S.P.Soni, look in tape options

Comment: Did you try to check if you have plugins that handles redirections?

What is your hosting company? Maybe you could ask for help from their technical support.